# Rails 4.2 Rails.application.config.assets.version doesn't invalidate digest asset file names

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, version, assets, precompile

I have a Rails 4.2.4 (Ruby 2.2.2) application and I am serving static assets via Cloudfront.

If Cloudfront is serving something you don't want, there are two possibilities:

- Invalidate the content in Cloudfront or
- Change the name of the asset served

However, when i change

Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

to

Rails.application.config.assets.version = '2.0'

(in config/initializers/assets.rb)

and

- delete all the assets in public/assets
- run "RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake assets:precompile"

the same file names are generated!

The only way i found to invalidate the digested file of application.scss was to add some dummy content in order to provoke a new md5 checksum.

What am i doing wrong?

Shouldn't a new assets.version change the digested file names?

Best Regards and thanx!

Comment: Note: I've added a Rails PR around this as well: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22472

Answer (score 9):

As per [the comments in the Rails pull request I opened](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22472#issuecomment-161464750), this is a regression that needs to be fixed: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/240

Update: As sansarp mentions, one of the workarounds listed in that github issue is to use an old version of sprockets:

```
gem 'sprockets', '< 3.0.0'
```

Another workaround is to use the asset path as a cache breaker instead:

```
# config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.prefix = "/assets/v1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using sprockets of previous version could help you to get file names as expected. `gem 'sprockets', '< 3.0.0'` https://github.com/rails/sprockets

Answer (score 0):

If you use capistrano for deployment be sure to set `assets_prefix` in the `deploy.rb` file.

```
set :assets_prefix, "assets/v1"
```